# How do you set the trim setting for a video in PowerPoint using VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have the same video positioned on multiple slides, but instead of starting from the beginning at each slide, I want it to commence playback from where the previous slide ended.

My idea for approaching this is to have a macro that automatically starts at the beginning of the presentation and just records the time somewhere. Then, upon slide transition, check the time again and determine where the video should be trimmed to on the new slide. The problem is that I can't find any way to set the trim/seek point using VBA. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with a similar issue, I did find a solution.

`ActivePresentation.Slides("your slide").Shapes("your shape").MediaFormat.StartPoint = yourStartPoint`